# Can my motherboard support Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, 64-bit

I want to upgrade my Windows7 32-bit to Windows10 64-bit. All my components support 64-bit. But in [the page](https://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_SPEC/ES/Motherboard/H61H2-M2%20-LL-V1-DO-0-RR-/Socket%201155-LL-Intel-RR-) the OS support only goes to Windows8 64-bit. Would it be a problem if I update to Windows 10?

Comment: Memory may be the only thing you need to upgrade, how much memory does it have?

Comment: If it has less than 4 GB of memory I wouldn't bother. Windows 10 will work with as little as 2 GB, but it will be painfully slow and not really useful due to excess paging.

Comment: I have 4GB of Ram installed and Windows 7 Starter Pack 32-bit. This OS limite my Ram to only 2GB. This is one of the reasons I want the update. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any machine that supports Windows 8 has also supported Windows 10 in our experience. So it should work.

You cannot upgrade a 32-bit system to a 64-bit system in place.

You need to back up everything and install Windows 10 fresh.

Windows 10 64-bit is much more flexible than Windows 10 32-bit.

Comment: This, and the manual was probably written before Windows10 was a thing.

Comment: It is a basic H61 motherboard. Will do Windows 10 64-bit just fine. Everything on that motherboard should be supported by Windows 10 build-in drivers.

Comment: Yes I am planning buy a SSD, install windows 10 and use it for the start of windows. Im gonna use the old HDD for storage. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @roman That makes sense. A SSD would make a huge difference.